# first() in Laravel return the first row in table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new with Laravel. I use the find(3)->first() function in destroy($id) method of controller to look up for the row that i want to delete in the database like below

```
$car = Car::where('id', $id)->first();
$car->delete();
```

Surprisingly the snippet returns the record with id=1, which is the first row in the table, not the row i want to delete.
I've been searching through the document of Laravel as well as googling some familiar questions but still not figure out what the's point. Why that snippet return the first row always?

Comment: You shouldn't call find(3)->first(); Find already returns the eloquent model. Try to just call $car = Car::find($id);

Comment: @Girish That is incorrect. It is perfectly fine to use where('id', $id); Which can be read in the exact place you linked Girish. "For convenience, if you want to verify that a column is = to a given value, you may pass the value as the second argument to the where method. Laravel will assume you would like to use the = operator:"

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank indeed, i didn't go through to below paragraph 

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `first()` function together with `find()`.

Method `find($id)` already returns single model instance, while Eloquent `first()` returns first instance in Eloquent Collection.

Second thing is that [delete()](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_delete) (<- look api documentation) returns boolean value if deletion was successful. Meaning, if model was deleted it will return value 1 (meaning true).

Following code will work as expected.

```
$model = Model::findOrFail($id);
$model->delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use find($id) like this

```
$car = Car::find($id);
$car->delete();
```

or you can write it in this way

```
$car = Car::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

check the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#deleting-models

Answer (score 0):

This:

`$car = Car::where('id', $id)->first();`

Is absolutely equal to this:

`$car = Car::find($id);`

And for your special case there is even shorter option:

`Car::destroy($id);`